# Passing a randomly generated list as a parameter in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, benchmarking, io-monad, haskell-criterion

I am new to Haskell and really having trouble with the whole IO thing.

I am trying to find out how long it takes to traverse a list in haskell. I wanted to generate a list of random numbers and pass it as a parameter to a function so that I can print each element of the list. I am using CRITERION package for the benchmark. Here is the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import System.Random
import Control.Exception
import Criterion.Main

printElements [] = return ()
printElements (x:xs) = do print(x)
                          printElements xs

randomList 0 = return []
randomList n = do
  x  <- randomRIO (1,100)
  xs <- randomList (n-1)
  return (x:xs)


main = defaultMain [
  bgroup "printElements" [ bench "[1,2,3]"  $ whnf printElements (randomList 10)
               , bench "[4,5,6]"  $ whnf printElements [4,5,6,4,2,5]
               , bench "[7,8,9]"  $ whnf printElements [7,8,9,2,3,4]
               , bench "[10,11,12]" $ whnf printElements [10,11, 12,4,5]
               ]
  ]
```

Error when I run the code:

```
listtraversal.hs:18:67:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’ with actual type ‘IO [t0]’
    In the second argument of ‘whnf’, namely ‘(randomList 10)’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘whnf printElements (randomList 10)’
```

Comment: Try giving each function an explicit type signature.  Its a great exercise that is both informative at this stage of learning and helps localize compilation messages throughout all stages of your Haskell learning/use.

Comment: During the benchmark, you will be repeatedly executing `printElements foo` for some `foo`. Do you want `foo` to be different in each execution?

Comment: BTW with this benchmark you will largely be measuring how long it takes to print things, since generating random numbers and traversing a list take a negligible amount of time in comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put briefly, you need to *bind* your function to the `IO` value, instead of trying to *apply* it to the value wrapped inside the `IO` value.

```
-- instead of whnf printElements (randomList 10)
randomList 10 >>= whnf printElements
```

---

`randomList` does not return a list of values; it returns an `IO` action that, when executed, can produce a list of values. Ignoring the various constraints induced by the implementation, the type is

```
randomList :: (...) => t1 -> IO [t]  -- not t1 -> [t]
```

As such, you can't directly work with the list of values that the `IO` action can produce; you need to use the monad instance to *bind* the value to an appropriate function. `whnf printElements` is one such function; it takes a list and returns an `IO` action.

```
whnf printElements :: Show a => [a] -> IO ()
```

Instead of pulling the list out and passing it to `whnf printElements`, we "push" the function *into* an `IO` value using `>>=`. That operator's type, specialized to the `IO` monad, is

```
(>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
```

In this case, the first `IO a` value is the `IO [t]` value returned by `randomList`. `whnf printElements` is the `a -> IO b` function we bind to.
The result is a new `IO` value that take the first `IO` value, pulls out the wrapped value, applies the given function, and returns the result.

In other words, the `IO` monad itself takes care of pulling apart the result from `randomList` and applying your function to it, rather than you doing it explicitly.

---

(You might have noticed that I've said that `>>=` binds a value to a function and vice versa. It is perhaps more accurate to say that `>>=` binds them together into a single `IO` action.)

Comment: And of course `randomList 10 >>= whnf printElements` can also be written `do { list <- randomList 10; whnf printElements list }`, or `whnf printElements =<< randomList 10`, which makes it a bit clearer that bind is an *application* operator (apply impure function to impure argument) like `$` (pure function to pure argument) and `<$>` (pure function to impure argument).